# Mysql synchronization, Result: 1031

Tags: mysql, synchronization, navicat

I'm beginning with mysql and I'm trying to synchronization data from one database (source) to another database (new database that created) using synchronization with data tools of mysql workbench and Navicat.

I tried both paths (mysql workbench and navicat software) and get the same error with some tables of the source database:

**Result: 1031 - Table storage engine for *'tablename'* doesn't have this option**

I know this error is based on the `ROW_FORMAT:FIXED` parameter of the source table, I tried to use `innodb_strict_mode = off` in command but didn't worked.
I don't have access to the source database structure so I can't change the `ROW_FORMAT`

Source mysql database version (old version): 5.5.34
Target mysql database version: 8.0.27

Any idea how I could fix this problem or another way to synchronization these two database?

Comment: If you want to sync the data, then you do not need to sync the underlying table properties like the row format

Comment: Thanks Shadow! sync only the data worked